# Reference to a part of an algorithm

Tags: hyperref, algorithm2e

I would like to write about the analysis of an algorithm. Depending on some conditions multiple cases arise. I would like to reference the cases but *not* solely based [on the line numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66217/is-there-a-way-to-reference-the-line-number-in-algorithm-2e). Essentially I want custom labels which work with hyperref.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\vspace{2em}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section \tcp*[f]{Case (1)} \;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\end{algorithm}

Analyis: Consider Case (1).

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) provides the means to set custom line numbers *and* reference them via `\nlset` together with a regular `\label`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\newcommand{\algcaseref}{Case~\ref}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      \nlset{(1)}\label{case:1}go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      \nlset{(B)}\label{case:2}go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
\end{algorithm}

Analysis: Consider \algcaseref{case:1}. Also consider \algcaseref{case:2}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating a custom counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{cases}
\newcommand{\case}[1]{\refstepcounter{cases}\label{#1}}

\begin{document}

\vspace{2em}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section \tcp*[f]{Case (1)} \case{mycase} \;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\end{algorithm}

Analyis: Consider Case (\ref{mycase}).

\end{document}
```

In this MWE, the `\case{}` command both increases the `cases` counter and labels the case according to that counter.

Comment: Well, I don't actually need any numbering at all. I just want a label that I can reference. It just needs to work properly with hyperref, i.e. when I click on the reference I get shown the relevant part of the algorithm

Comment: @hfhc2 I'm not sure what you mean. If you load the hyperref package, clicking on the label (1) will take you to the relevant part of the algorithm.

Comment: I added the inclusion of `hyperref` to my MWE.